# Swiffy 7.3 doesn't work with older swiffy files

Tags: google-swiffy

I've been using swiffy5 to convert flash files with simple animations into swiffyobjects. Google has recently updated swiffy to version 7.3 which is incompatible with the swiffy5 runtime file. Swiffy objects made up until now are also incompatible with the swiffy 7.3 runtime file. Is there anyway to convert flash files using older versions of swiffy?

Comment: I am facing same issue... Any solution found would be great helpful. Thank you.